# postgraphile ignore table name start with ACT

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

why post graphile ignore table name start with act like action it appear in the query and mutation but not in documentation explorer but i try to create different table like abc, awc but only table name act or even start with act like action not showing in documentation explorer
[image: graphql documentation explorer]